# How to alternate sibling Vue component v-for renderings for a shared array in a list in the parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following challenge to work on and thanks for any input:

> From 'App' use 'TestListItem' when an item index is odd and
> 'TestListBetterItem' when item index is even. Must use the same index for both components.

I have tried setting the keys for my two separate child components as being equal to odd and the other to even but I receive a duplicate key error. I need to pass in alternating values from two child components into a shared parent component. The full code is below:

> App.vue

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <test-list-item>
    </test-list-item>
    <test-list-better-item>     
    </test-list-better-item>
  </div>
</template>

          <!-- <template #title>
            I AM A HEADER
          </template> -->
          <!-- <template #footer>
          I AM A FOOTER
          </template> -->

<script>
import { TestBetterList, TestListItem, TestListBetterItem } from './components';


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { TestBetterList, TestListItem, TestListBetterItem },
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['better-item-1',  'better-item-2', 'better-item-3']
    };
  },
  //   watch: {
  //       'better-item-1': {
  //     handler: 'oddMethod',
  //     immediate: true,
  //     deep:true
  //   },
  //       'better-item-2': {
  //     handler: 'evenMethod',
  //     immediate: true,
  //     deep: true
  //   },
  //       'better-item-3': {
  //     handler: 'oddMethod',
  //     immediate: true,
  //     deep: true
  //   },
  // },
  methods: {

  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

> TestListItem.vue

```
    <template>
  <div class="test-list-item">
        <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <slot>
        <div :key="index">{{ item }}</div>
      </slot>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'test-list-item',
  props: {

  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['better-item-1',  'better-item-2', 'better-item-3']
    };
  },
  computed: {
   
},
  mounted() {
  },
  created() {},

    //   methods: {
    //     oddMethod: function () {
    //     items[0]
    //   }
    // }

};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.test-list-item {
  color: purple
}


</style>
```

> TestListBetterItem.vue

```
    <template>
  <div class="test-list-better-item">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <slot>
        <div :key="index">{{ item }}</div>
      </slot>
    </template>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'test-list-better-item',
  props: {

  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['better-item-1',  'better-item-2', 'better-item-3']
    };
  },
  computed: {
   
},
  mounted() {
  },
  created() {},

    //   methods: {
    //     evenMethod: function () {
    //     items[0]
    //   }
    // }

};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.test-list-better-item {
  color: rgb(255, 145, 0)
}


</style>
```

Comment: Sorry, Loren, I don't think I understand the task the same way as you, can you please explain further? From what I read in the task specification, it'd go like that: `App.vue` contains a list of items, you iterate through this list, for even indices you generate a `'TestListItem'` component, and for odd indices you generate a `TestListBetterItem` component... Both accept the same `:index` as props, and the decision's made using `v-if` directive. Did I misunderstand the task? Because your code is something entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the task you're facing, but it seems to me it's about the conditional rendering of two different types of list items, not about the creation of two separate lists. So when it refers to `TestListItem` and `TestListBetterItem` those are components representing **list items**, and the actual array containing the list is still in the `App` component. So I'd first create two separate components by these names, and then apply the `v-if` and `v-else` directives to choose which of those to render based on the index of the list item being rendered.

```
<template> 
  <div id="app"> 
    <ul id="test-list"> 
      <li v-for="(listItem,listItemIndex) in testList"> 
         <TestListItem v-if="listItemIndex % 2 === 0" /> 
         <TestListBetterItem v-else /> 
      </li> 
    </test-list> 
  </div> 
</template>
```

I created a StackBlitz for you ( although I used Vue 3 for it, but you can migrate it easily back to Vue 2 ):

[CODE HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lists-for-loren?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do that Peta! The logic works great for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @LorenRachelleHicks Glad it helped you Loren :) Good luck with the rest of the challenges!